# How can I get faster compile times for a Rust web project?

Tags: web, rust, compilation

I've been working on a Rust program that generates static content for a website. It builds in about 600 milliseconds on my machine (not great but totally manageable).

I want to add some dynamic content, so I'm trying out Actix-Web, but it has increased the compile times to about 18-20 seconds, which is too high for me.

I know of two ways to fix this problem:

1. Rewrite my application as a CGI script. This eliminates the Actix dependency and should restore my ~600ms compile times.
2. Split my application into a web server and a binary that the web server calls whenever a route is accessed. This way I only have to compile the web server every time I make an API change, and I can interact with the binary via `stdin`/`stdout`.

These seem like hard to maintain hacks so I was wondering if there were other options in the Rust ecosystem. Are there other web frameworks I can use? IIRC Tide and Rocket are both as slow to compile as Actix. Are there tricks I can use to speed up Actix compile times? Are there other options I haven't thought of?

Note: I do not care even slightly about runtime performance. This is an application that only a handful of people will ever use.

Update: Here is an Actix example that I've been using:

```
use actix_session::Session;
use actix_session::{storage::CookieSessionStore, SessionMiddleware};
use actix_web::{get, Responder};
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

#[get("/session")]
async fn session(session: Session) -> impl Responder {
    let counter = match session.get::<i32>("counter") {
        Ok(counter) => match counter {
            Some(counter) => counter + 1,
            _ => 1,
        },
        _ => 1,
    };

    match session.insert("counter", counter) {
        _ => format!("You have visited {} times", counter),
    }
}

static SESSION_SIGNING_KEY: &[u8] = &[0; 64]; // Just an example

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let key = actix_web::cookie::Key::from(SESSION_SIGNING_KEY);

    let host = "0.0.0.0";
    let port = 8080;
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(
                SessionMiddleware::builder(CookieSessionStore::default(), key.clone())
                    .cookie_secure(false)
                    .build(),
            )
            .service(session)
    })
    .bind((host, port))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

If I do nothing but change the port number, the compilation takes up to 20 seconds.

```
   Compiling actix-test v0.1.0 (/home/sam/test)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 20.90s
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "actix-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-files = "0.6.2"
actix-session = { version = "0.7.2" , features = ["cookie-session"] }
actix-web = "4.2.1"
env_logger = "0.9.3"
log = "0.4.17"
serde = { version = "1.0.147", features = ["derive"] }
```

Comment: Compile times, unless egregiously long, should always take a backseat to maintainability and productivity. _"This is an application that only a handful of people will ever use"_ are words frequently uttered before creating an unmaintainable monstrosity that serves as an organization's technological linchpin for 20 years.

Comment: @cdhowie 18 seconds for an incremental build *is* egregiously long in 2023 and greatly hurts productivity by lengthening the iteration cycle. You are correct about maintainability, but the web component of this application is much less important than the business logic, so I am not too concerned about having a more maintainable web server, especially if it comes at such a high cost.

Comment: Indeed, but that seems more like an environmental issue as the build definitely should not be taking that long. The Axum project I am working on right now debug-builds (incrementally) in <4s.

Comment: Are you by any chance on windows(antivirus software on windows frequently causes severe IO perf degradation)?  Are you using a mechanical drive? What CPU are you using? What does CPU utilization during a build look like? What is your system linker?

Comment: @cdhowie Thats... why I asked the question? I'm trying to figure out why my performance is so bad.

Comment: I'm curious if your `Cargo.toml` specifies any build options. Turning on LTO, for example, adds quite a lot of build time.

Comment: @PiRocks I am on Linux using a mechanical drive. My CPU is an i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz. It looks like only one core is being used when I run a build. I assume I'm using ld as my linker but I don't know how to check.

Comment: @cdhowie I'll add my Cargo.toml.

Comment: Hmm, hard to say exactly what the problem could be.  There's no build options there. My environment is almost the same as yours: i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz on Linux, except I have an SSD. Regardless, the I/O cache should be more than sufficient to handle this build quickly on an HDD. Which version of rustc?

Comment: @Displayname you might check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343560/what-linker-was-used-to-build-a-rust-binary) thread for the linker.

Comment: It may be that the mechanical drive is the problem. There are various performance optimized linkers our there like mold that you may want to look into. You can check if your mechanical drive is the issue by moving your entire build/working dir and crates io cache  to /dev/shm and seeing if that improves things. Though you may or may not have enough ram to pull that off.

Comment: Additionally that CPU is quite old though I realize that you may not be able to do anything about that.

Comment: As a point of comparison on an ssd +  i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz + default gnu linker,  the above with a port number change only takes 3.8 seconds.

Comment: @PiRocks The issue was with my LSP. Rust-analyzer was causing some sort of locking and disabling it fixed the issue.

Comment: Might be worth answering your own question with that.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time developers compile in *debug* mode while developing, which is significantly faster than compiling in *release* mode, and only use *release* mode when needed, i.e. for the binary executables they want to actually deploy/distribute.

If an "empty" Actix project takes 18-20 seconds to compile, you're probably looking at compile times for *release* mode and you are probably compiling from a single (and not particularly fast) CPU core. Compiling from a powerful CPU with at least 4 cores should drop your build times significantly - perhaps somewhere around 3-6 seconds for release mode.

Also, it might be worth mentioning that the first time a project is built after some crates are added/updated to your project (in your `Cargo.toml` file), the build will take much longer than subsequent builds. I assume you're aware of that but am mentioning it just in case you've overlooked that part.

Comment: If you use 4 cores, those 18-20 seconds sound like too much to me, especially for debug mode. What is your CPU? On/for what OS are you compiling? Have you checked if all cores are utilized during the build?

Comment: I've updated my question with more background information. I'm on Linux with an i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz.

Comment: It seems like not all my cores are being used. Only one core goes to 100% during compile time.

Comment: Interesting. How are you building? Is it possible you're using settings that specifically restrict to 1 CPU core only? You could try something like `cargo b -j 4` and see if that helps.

Comment: The issue was with my LSP. Rust-analyzer was causing some sort of locking and disabling it fixed the issue.

Comment: Great! That's why one should care about build times - sometimes there is something that *could* be improved. ;)
Just curious, what are your build times now?

Comment: around 5 seconds, but it still varies quite a bit, so sometimes faster sometimes slower. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with rust-analyzer. I was using Neovim, but I also tried it out with VS-Code and got the same result. I think that somehow the LSP was locking the package so that Cargo had to wait each time to compile it... or something.

The fix is to kill rust-analyzer and restart your editor. My compile times for minor changes are now as low as two seconds, and about five on average.